# Read more / Read Less function on different <div>

Tags: jquery, html, loops, each

I am trying to implement a Read more / Read less function with Jquery on different  and

.

my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/d4riog7/wbnwvgnt/

```
$('.read_more').each(function() {

$(this).click(function() {

$('.more').slideToggle();

if ($(this).text() == moreText) {
  $(this).text(lessText);

} else {
  $(this).text(moreText);

}

});

});
```

- As you can see from the fiddle, I cannot use the Read More and Read Less links independentently for each paragraph as they all show/hide at the same time (although I thought I looped through all of them with each().
- Also the text changes from "Read More +" to "Read Less -" on click, but not properly.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong while looping, any suggestions? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to esignation what `.more` is you want to use,

```
$(this).parent('.main').find('.more').slideToggle();
```

when click in `.read_more`

find the parent `.main` then find `.more` in `main`

sorry for my english , hope help

```js
moreText = "Read More +",
lessText = "Read Less -";

$('.read_more').click(function() {

  $(this).parent('.main').find('.more').slideToggle();

  if ($(this).text() == moreText) {
    $(this).text(lessText);

  } else {
    $(this).text(moreText);

  }

});
```

```css
.more {
  display: none;
}

.read_more {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

  <h3>Lorem ipsum </h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p class="more">Sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim</p>
  <a class="read_more">Read More +</a>
</div>


<div class="main">

  <h3>Ipsum dolor</h3>
  <p>Laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim </p>
  <p class="more">consectetuer sed diam nonummy nibh euismod adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibhLorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <a class="read_more">Read More +</a>
</div>

<div class="main">

  <h3>Ipsum dolor</h3>
  <p>Laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim </p>
  <p class="more">consectetuer sed diam nonummy nibh euismod adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibhLorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <a class="read_more">Read More +</a>
</div>
```